# Laravel 5. Retrieve data from DB::select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Code:

```
        $best_price = DB::select('Some SQL statement');

        foreach($best_price as $best_price_id) {
            $best_price_id->id;
        };

       
        $product->best_price_id = $best_price_id;

        return $product->best_price_id;
```

Result:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
> __toString(), "object" given.

I am definitely retrieving information from the DB incorrectly. Please suggest better option.

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results It seems you need to do  DB::table('<table name>') instead of DB::select('')

Comment: example  DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();

Comment: You write about query builder but I use raw query. Currently for me is too hard to transform my SQL statement in query builder statement.

Comment: Can you please var_dump( $best_price_id ) ;  ?

Comment: Thank you! $best_price_id is an array and I should have written `product->best_price_id = $best_price_id->id`. But now I have another question: in my case foreach shows only the first element of array, while there are 7 inside. What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you var_dump( $best_price  ) and add the output to your question ?

Comment: check my answer  $best_price_id is not an array.

Comment: I will help you finding solution, but you should accept my answer is correct as it has solved your problem for which you have posted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to which  return $product->best_price_id; is returning value is expecting string and you are supplying an object, You need to do

```
product->best_price_id = $best_price_id->id;
```

in place of `product->best_price_id = $best_price_id;`